# jest + supertest: how to reset the mocked dependency

Tags: javascript, express, jestjs, integration-testing, supertest

I am not able to reset jest mocks of a dependency after it's being used once by [supertest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest). I appreciate any help or hint.

The following is my api test with supertest:

```
import request from 'supertest';
import router from '../index';
const app = require('express')();
app.use(router);

jest.mock('config', () => ({}));

jest.mock('express-request-proxy', () => data => (req, res, next) =>
  res.json(data),
);

beforeEach(() => {
  jest.resetAllMocks();
});

describe('GET /', () => {
  it('should get all stuff', () =>
    request(app)
      .get('')
      .expect(200)
      .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
      .then(response => {
        expect(response.body).toMatchSnapshot();             // all good here 
      }));

  it('should get all stuff when FOO=bar', async () => {
    jest.mock('config', () => ({
      FOO: 'bar',
      get: key => key,
    }));

    // >> HERE <<
    // config.FOO is still undefined!
    // reseting mocks did not work ...
    await request(app)
      .get('')
      .expect(200)
      .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
      .then(response => {
        expect(response.body.query).toHaveProperty('baz');   // test fails ...
      });
  });
});
```

express.js api:

```
const router = require('express').Router({ mergeParams: true });
import config from 'config';
import proxy from 'express-request-proxy';

router.get('', (...args) => {
  let query = {};
  if (config.FOO === 'bar') {
    query.baz = true;
  }
  return proxy({
    url: '/stuff',
    query,
  })(...args);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use [jest.mock(moduleName, factory, options)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) in a function scope, it should be used in the module scope. You should use [jest.doMock(moduleName, factory, options)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestdomockmodulename-factory-options) if you want to arrange the mocks in function scope of test cases.

We also need to use [jest.resetModules()](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestresetmodules) before executing each test case to

> reset the module registry - the cache of all required modules.

It means your `./config` module registry will be reset so that it will return different mocked values for each test case when you require it after `jest.doMock('./config', () => {...})` statement.

`{ virtual: true }` option means I don't install the `express-request-proxy` package so it doesn't exist in my `npm_modules` directory. If you had already installed it, you can remove this option.

Here is the unit test solution:

`index.js`:

```js
const router = require('express').Router({ mergeParams: true });

import config from './config';
import proxy from 'express-request-proxy';

router.get('', (...args) => {
  console.log(config);
  let query = {};
  if (config.FOO === 'bar') {
    query.baz = true;
  }
  return proxy({ url: '/stuff', query })(...args);
});

export default router;
```

`config.js`:

```js
export default {
  FOO: '',
};
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
import request from 'supertest';

jest.mock('express-request-proxy', () => (data) => (req, res, next) => res.json(data), { virtual: true });

beforeEach(() => {
  jest.resetAllMocks();
  jest.resetModules();
});

describe('GET /', () => {
  it('should get all stuff', () => {
    jest.doMock('./config', () => ({}));
    const router = require('./index').default;
    const app = require('express')();
    app.use(router);

    return request(app)
      .get('')
      .expect(200)
      .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
      .then((response) => {
        expect(response.body).toMatchSnapshot();
      });
  });

  it('should get all stuff when FOO=bar', async () => {
    jest.doMock('./config', () => ({
      default: {
        FOO: 'bar',
        get: (key) => key,
      },
      __esModule: true,
    }));
    const router = require('./index').default;
    const app = require('express')();
    app.use(router);

    await request(app)
      .get('')
      .expect(200)
      .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
      .then((response) => {
        expect(response.body.query).toHaveProperty('baz');
      });
  });
});
```

unit test results with 100% coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/61828748/index.test.js (11.966s)
  GET /
    ✓ should get all stuff (8710ms)
    ✓ should get all stuff when FOO=bar (24ms)

  console.log
    {}

      at stackoverflow/61828748/index.js:7:11

  console.log
    { FOO: 'bar', get: [Function: get] }

      at stackoverflow/61828748/index.js:7:11

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   1 passed, 1 total
Time:        13.268s
```

`index.test.js.snap`:

```
// Jest Snapshot v1

exports[`GET / should get all stuff 1`] = `
Object {
  "query": Object {},
  "url": "/stuff",
}
`;
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/tree/master/stackoverflow/61828748